# Fish like ls keybinding in Zsh

Tags: zsh

In the fish shell, when you press `Alt+l` it displays the output of the `ls` command nicely. It keeps the command you were writing before you pressed it. I would like to have this in zsh.

This was my very wonky attempt:

```
function myls {
    awk '{len = length($0); for(i=0;i<len;i++) printf "\b"}' <<< "$LBUFFER"
    zle push-input
    zle accept-line
    print $(ls --color=always --indicator-style=slash)
}
zle -N myls
bindkey -- '^[l' myls
```

I struggled to get the existing command to clear, and ended up using hacky `\b`'s. It does not work correctly on long and multi lines.

Can anyone do any better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zle -R` after the `push-input` to redisplay the line without the buffer.

For the most part, I find zsh's completion listing obviates the need for a widget to run ls. It does ls style colors and file-type suffixes. I have the following binding 
which does file completion in any context and does a long, `ls -l` style listing:

```
zstyle ":completion:file-complete::::" completer _files
zle -C file-complete complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:file-complete:*' file-list true
bindkey '^X^F' file-complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to input from @okapi I came up with this.

```
function myls {
    [[ "$CONTEXT" = cont ]] && return
    zle push-input
    zle -R
    zle accept-line
    print -n $(ls --color=always --indicator-style=slash)
}

zle -N myls
bindkey -- '^[l' myls
```

It's much better, but it wasn't working with the continuation like in loops 'for> ...' and 'while> ...' so I have it just return in them for now.